# SetTimeout and setInterval in an asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, settimeout, setinterval

```
   var processStatusCheck = setInterval(function statusCheck() {
    sequelize.query(dbQuery).then(function (data) {
       winston.info(' Status:', importStatus);
      if (importStatus ===  true) {
        winston.info('Inside', pollCount);
        clearInterval(processStatusCheck);
        addProcess(Id, function (response) {
               res.send(200)
        });
      } else {
        if(pollCount > 15){
          winston.info('It came here !!!', pollCount);
           res.sendStatus(500);      
        }else{
          winston.info('Incrementing.....');
          pollCount++;
          setTimeout(statusCheck, 18000);
        }
      }
    });
  }, 5000);
```

I am trying to implement an asynchronous Javascript function. I want to continuously query the Database till the status becomes true,

Initially the call is made after 5 seconds, as per the setInterval but once it reaches the setTimeout, it continuously calls the function. I want it to be called after 18 secconds. 
If the time is less than 5 seconds in setTimmeout, response is sent immediately and I am getting "Can't set headers after they are sent" error.

Does having a setInterval and setTimeout causing me a problem here ? Please guide me.

Comment: It is unclear what logic you want.  Please describe the precise polling logic you want in words.  It's also unclear to me why you have both a `setInterval()` and a `setTimeout()`.  The problem with "can't set headers after they are sent" is caused when you try to call `res.send()` more than once.  Also, what is `importStatus` and how does it relate to your polling logic.  It isn't defined or changed in the code you show.

Comment: It looks to me that if `importStatus` is not `true`, then you NEVER clear your `setInterval()`.  It just keeps running forever and once pollCount > 15, you keep doing `res.sendStatus(500)` on every tick of the interval timer.

Comment: I want to poll untill the result becomes true. But if it goes beyond a certain count, then don't poll. This is what I'm trying to implement. The importStatus is the result of the db call. It provides whether the value is true or false. I'm not able to get a clear on how to clean this. I don't actually want to use both settimeout and setInterval. Sorry for the bad code.

Comment: In the code you show `importStatus` is not defined and does not have anything to do with the `sequelize.query()` result that you show.  In fact, you don't do anything with that database result in this code.  So, I don't understand what you're polling for?  Is this really all the relevant code?  Or, did you leave something out?

Comment: FYI, at a minimum, you are probably missing a `clearInterval(processStatusCheck)` somewhere because if `importStatus` never comes `true`,, then you never stop the interval, even though you've already done `res.sendStatus(500)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still don't follow the desired logic as you have not really explained how you expect it to work.  I will describe what you are doing and point out several flaws in that flow.

1. You start an interval that runs every 5 seconds.
2. That runs until `importStatus` becomes `true`, but nothing in this loop ever sets `importStatus` so it appears to never be satisfied.
3. You do a database query inside the loop, but never even refer to the result of the database query.  I assume that can't be right.  Again, there must be some code missing from what you posted.
4. Then, after 15 iterations of the interval, you also start doing a `setTimeout()` every 18 seconds.
5. So, both the 5 second interval and the 18 second `setTimeout()` are both running.
6. Then, after 15 iterations, you do `res.sendStatus(500)`, but never stop the `setInterval()` which keeps running and keeps trying to do `res.sendStatus(500)` every time it fires.

Summary of problems:

1. Nothing in this code ever does anything with `importStatus` so it will never be `true` based on this code.  I'm assuming your real code must be different than what you show here.
2. If `importStatus` is never `true` (see previous point), then you never stop the interval - it runs for ever.  You need to be stopping the interval timer, probably in a couple places.  Certainly stop it when you do `res.sendStatus(500)` and probably also stop it when you start doing `setTimeout()`.
3. After 15 iterations of the interval, you start doing a `setTimeout()` set for 18 seconds.  So, now both the interval and the `setTimeout()` are both running.  It seems unlikely you want that.  Perhaps you should be stopping the `setInterval()` when you start doing the `setTimeout()`
4. `addProcess()` shows an asynchronous style callback interface, but has no opportunity for error handling.  Is it really a function that can have no errors?
5. You never even refer to `data` which is the database query result so the query is never used.

Edit from your comment:

> This is the logic I want to implement.  1) Poll the Database for 15 times , every 10 seconds . 2) Even after 1 and half minutes, if the status is not true, send 500 and stop the process.

Well, the 15 times, 10 seconds each and 1-1/2 minutes don't all add up.  15 times at 10 seconds each would be 150 seconds which would be 2-1/2 minutes.  Here's an implementation that does 15 times at 10 seconds.  You can adjust the numbers to be whatever you want.

```
  let pollCount = 0;
  const processStatusCheck = setInterval(function statusCheck() {
    sequelize.query(dbQuery).then(function (data) {
       if (someCondition) {
            clearInterval(processStatusCheck);
            addProcess(Id, function (response) {
               res.send(200)
            });
       } else {
            ++pollCount;
            if (pollCount > 15) {
                clearInterval(processStatusCheck);
                res.sendStatus(500);
            }
       }
  }, 10 * 1000);
```

Comment: No actually, I have hidden a few parts of the code. The `importStatus` value is actually set from the `data` . Ideally I want to stop the polling and exit the entire function after 15 iterations.   

Your assumption on `importStatus` is true.    
`addProcess` has error handlers in my real code, Just to avoid a huge code here, I have removed it.   

This is the logic I want to implement @jfriend00  
1) Poll the Database for 15 times , every 10 seconds . 
2) Even after 1 and half minutes, if the status is not true, send 500 and stop the process.

Comment: @Kumar - Well, I added an implementation to my answer that does what you put in your comment.

Comment: @Kumar - If this answers your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.